# Emulate dynamic loader to fixup shared library offsets

Tags: c++, c, embedded, shared-libraries

I have an interesting situation at work that I am trying to find a good solution for. We have code that runs on a multi-core MIPS bare metal (no kernel). We have a requirement to integrate with some 3rd party code that needs to be upgradable.
I was thinking of compiling the 3rd party code as PIC and then change the GOT for the code/data symbols when I download this code (I have control over where the code will reside). Also, assume the interfaces into the 3rd party code dont change so there are no new PLT/GOT entries.
Will this work?. What other things should I be considering?.

Comment: I have to say, while I think this is swimming in the very-deep end of a very-localized question, I simply cannot bring myself to down-vote it (and in fact up-voted instead), as it is just way too damn intriguing an idea and curiosity has won me over (and apparently others as well). Good luck!

Comment: @vamsi The question is a bit unclear to me.
Do you mean change the GOT every time you load a new version of the 3rd party (upgrade)? Are you asking how to write a loader yourself?

Comment: @selalerer Yes, I meant change the GOT everytime I load a new 3rd party version. Yes, in essence what I would end up having is a lightweight loader. I dont want to implement a full ledged loader. All I want to do is fixup the GOT/PLT tables and get the new code active.

Comment: @vamsi Is there no ready made dynamic loader for this architecture that you can use?

Comment: @selalerer No there isnt one ready to use. Will post a note on this thread once I am done doing what I intended to do. Cheers.

Comment: Something that could be solved by loading an object dynamically? Or just get enough of the shared library machinery running to solve your problem? Maybe you _can_ solve this, but I guess it will hurt a lot more than the above (or install a operating system underneath).

Answer (score 1):

Is the correct answer longer than "embed a dynamic linker/loader"? Your problem seems the same as that solved by ld.so and the likes. Describing all the things which a dynamic linker/loader must consider is the topic of books such as [Linkers and Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) by John Levine.

Comment: I am looking for something simpler than writing my own embedded loader. I have read the book you mention above. When I am done working through my problem I will post what I ended up doing. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Would the Linux/Unix binutils `objcopy` be what you are looking for. Assuming that you are building all your binaries at once, rather than actually wanting to dynamically load them at runtime in random order [and you don't have enough memory to spread them out across that memory], then I think that would work.

Of course, if you ONLY need to fix up the GOT, then I don't see why you can't just do that - it's not that difficult a task to write somethingt hat does that. But objcopy is already written, and can do quite a bit of binary/executable "messing about" (I've used it to make boot-roms for various systems, including BIOS roms for PC's and the like) [Not that I came up with the idea, more like I took someone's makefile, which happened to have objcopy inside it - I just looked at what it did to understand how it made the rom when something was going wrong at one point or another]